# Set state of selected value with more than one dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent `<FirstStep />` component that contains two dropdowns components.
I need to set the `state` of the selected values.

If I have only one dropdown that code works fine but I have two dropdowns so I can't just pass in the `onChange` because each dropdown will need an `onChange`.

`<FirstStep />` component:

```
const items = [
    { name: 'aa', value: 1 },
    { name: 'bb', value: 2 },
    { name: 'cc', value: 3 },
];

export default ({ active, onChange, selection }) => (
    <Card active={active}>
        <CardHeader text="Please choose" >
            <Circle active small text="1" />
        </CardHeader>
        <Dropdown items={items} placeholder="Please choose" onChange={onChange} selection={selection}/> 
        <Dropdown items={[{ name: "dd", value: 1 }]} selection="Please choose" />
    </Card>
);
```

And `<FirstStep />` story:

```
storiesOf('FirstStep', module)
    .add('default', () => (
        <StateContainer state={{ selected: '' }}>
            {({ state, setState }) => (
                <FirstStep onChange={selection => setState({ selected: selection.name })}
                    selection={state.selected} />
            )}
        </StateContainer>
    ));
```

Please advise how I can set the `state` of the selected values if I have a few dropdowns in my component.

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass a second onChange in to FirstStep for your second Dropdown or use the same onChange function and pass in an identifier or something similar.

Or if both dropdowns are intended to modify the same value in the state (state.selected in this case) you can just set the same onChange to the second Dropdown as well.

```
<FirstStep onChange={selection => setState({ selected: selection.name })}
           onChange2={selection => setState({ selectedB: selection.name })}
           selection={state.selected} />

export default ({ active, onChange, onChange2, selection }) => (
<Card active={active}>
    <CardHeader text="Please choose" >
        <Circle active small text="1" />
    </CardHeader>
    <Dropdown items={items} placeholder="Please choose" onChange={onChange} selection={selection}/> 
    <Dropdown items={[{ name: "dd", value: 1 }]} selection="Please choose" onChange={onChange2} />
</Card>
);
```

or

```
<FirstStep
  selection={state.selected} 
  onChange={(ident, selection) => {
    if(ident ===1) {
      setState({selected: selection.name}) 
    } else {
      setState({selectedB: selection.name})
    }}}
/>

export default ({ active, onChange, selection }) => (
<Card active={active}>
    <CardHeader text="Please choose" >
        <Circle active small text="1" />
    </CardHeader>
    <Dropdown items={items} placeholder="Please choose" onChange={(selected) => onChange(1, selected)} selection={selection}/> 
    <Dropdown items={[{ name: "dd", value: 1 }]} selection="Please choose" onChange={(selected) => onChange(2, selected)}/>
</Card>
```

);

or just

```
export default ({ active, onChange, selection }) => (
<Card active={active}>
    <CardHeader text="Please choose" >
        <Circle active small text="1" />
    </CardHeader>
    <Dropdown items={items} placeholder="Please choose" onChange={onChange} selection={selection}/> 
    <Dropdown items={[{ name: "dd", value: 1 }]} selection="Please choose" onChange={onChange}/>
</Card>
```

);

if they both modify state.selected.

These are just to give you an idea of alternatives, obviously you need to adapt them to your own needs.